# Exit silent mode without vibrate

Tags: iphone, vibrate, sound-volume

When using the hardware switch on the side of my iPhone to change from silent mode to non-silent mode, the phone vibrates once.

How can I turn off this vibrate?

There is no vibration from non-silent mode to silent mode.

Comment: I think you have it backwards...? My iPhone 7 vibrates when going _into_ silent mode via the hardware switch. Not sure if it's possible to change this, BTW.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 Nope. I recheked my iPhone and wording on this post. I have it correct (iPhone 6). Yours would definitely be more annoying for me (vibrate when going *into* silent mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Settings --> Sounds and then turn off vibrate on ring

Use the hardware switch and re-enable vibrate on ring